# How to calculate a definite integral like $\int_a^xf(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}?$

Tags: calculus, integration

What theorems/tools should I know to solve a definite integral that has $x$ for $b$ (the upper limit of integration) and $t$ inside the equation, such as the integral
$$\int_1^x{\frac{1}{t^2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}$$

We currently went over this in class for my calc2 course but he never explained why he did what he did and help hours don't start till this upcoming Monday. I feel like I may have gone over this in Calc1, but I've forgotten it.

Any help on how to solve problems like this would be extremely appreciated, such as where to start for solving, why you're doing what you're doing, etc.

Comment: do you mean $$\int_a^x f(t)dt$$?

Comment: yes I just made an account for this question so I wasn’t sure how to create the actual equation on here on my laptop

Answer (score 4):

The only theorem you'll need to solve this class of problem is the second part of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

**Theorem** (Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)**.** *Let $f$ be an integrable function over some domain $X \supseteq [a,b]$. Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$. Then*
$$\int_a^b{f(x)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}} = F(b) - F(a)\,\text{.}$$

We can use this theorem to solve problems of your class: by substitution, we have
$$\int_a^x{f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = F(x) - F(a)\,\text{.}$$

Using this for your example problem, we wish to calculate $\int_1^x{1/t^{2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}}$. Thus, our function is $f(t) = 1/t^{2}$. Let's find an antiderivative of this function.
$$F(t) = \int{f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t} = }\int{\frac{1}{t^2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = \int{t^{-2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = -t^{-1} + C = -\frac{1}{t} + C\,\text{.}$$

We can choose any antiderivative of $f$ we want, so we'll set $C = 0$.

Thus, $F(t) = -1/t$. So,
$$\int_1^x{\frac{1}{t^2}\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = \int_1^x{f(t)\mathop{\mathrm{d}t}} = F(x) - F(1) = -\frac{1}{x} + 1\,\text{.}$$

Often, you might see $F(b) - F(a)$ notated as $F(x)\Big|_{x=a}^b$ or $\Big[F(x)\Big]_{x = a}^b$. These all mean the same thing.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help